# Android Keyboard output unicode string and label with unsupported glyph

Tags: android, unicode, android-input-method

I'm working on an Android IME which is for a native American language which has characters which are not single unicode code points but unicode strings.  For example, a glottalized barred lambda: ƛ̕

I'm finding myself in a catch-22 because I can either create a Key which outputs the right character but doesn't have the right label or I can have the right label but the wrong output.  I should say that I've been trying to accomplish this in xml and I think the relevant attributes are these:

- `android:codes`
- `android:keyLabel`
- `android:keyOutputText`
- `android:keyIcon`

More detail:

From what I've been able to find out, it's impossible to change the font on a keyLabel because the system's `DEFAULT_BOLD` font is hard-coded into the Keyboard class.  Therefore I can't use the following to properly define the key:

```
<Key android:keyOutputText="@string/glot_barred_lambda"
     android:keyLabel="@string/glot_barred_lambda"/>
```

(where the string constant `glot_barred_lambda` is defined as "ƛ̕" in the relevant location)

The issue is that the default Android font doesn't support this glyph.

Therefore I thought I had to make an icon for the keylabel.  I did so.  However, this definition gives a NullPointerError:

```
<Key android:keyOutputText="@string/glot_barred_lambda" 
     android:keyIcon="@drawable/keyboard_barred_lambda" />`
```

The issue seems to be that `keyOutputText` is not compatible with `keyIcon`. (I have no idea why!).  So that left me trying this:

```
<Key android:codes="411,789" 
     android:keyIcon="@drawable/keyboard_barred_lambda" />
```

This compiles and runs fine, but doesn't give the right behaviour.  The key label looks great, but the output is just the barred lambda (the 411) on a single tap and just a combining diacritic on a double tap (the 789).

I've run out of ideas so I'm looking forward to some advice from the real experts.  Thanks a lot for reading and I 'm happy to clarify my question as you guys need me to.

Comment: Maybe the answer to my question likes in defining a KeyCharacterMap.  However the docs [link](http://source.android.com/devices/tech/input/key-character-map-files.html) don't seem to be addressing my desideratum (outputting a Unicode string and labelling the key with an Icon).  Love to hear from an expert.

Comment: Man it is lonely out here in minority-language territory. I am trying something similar in 2017 and my (much simpler) challenge is that we have all our project documentation in U+nnnn hex form and the xml file seems to prefer the decimal keys like nnn. I can recalculate of course but since I have known the hex-codes for ages, it is annoying. Also I can not find how to string several codes in U+nnnn form. Maybe you can have a look at my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46415840/how-can-i-list-several-unicode-codes-for-an-android-soft-keyboard    thank you.

Comment: What you call "docs link" have probably moved. The closest I could find is now here (Oct 2017): https://source.android.com/devices/input/key-character-map-files

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found an answer which may be a bit of a kludge, but it works and allows the desired functionality of Keys which output unicode strings and have icons as labels.

Since `android:keyOutputText` won't work on a key which has an `android:keyIcon`, I was forced to use `android:codes`.  Although `android:codes` doesn't output strings, I found that I could assign negative numbers as personal codes in the XML and then use those codes to assign my own output text in java.

For example, in the XML:

```
<Key android:codes="-1001" 
     android:keyIcon="@drawable/keyboard_barred_lambda" />
...
```

And then in my IME.java in `handleCharacter`:

```
private void handleCharacter(int primaryCode, int[] keyCodes) {
    ...
    if (isAlphabet(primaryCode) && mPredictionOn) {
    ...
    } else {
        // handling composing characters here now because
        // android won't let us use an icon along with outputText
        // this is dirty!
        if(primaryCode == -1001) {
          getCurrentInputConnection().commitText("ƛ̕", 1);
        } else if(primaryCode == -1002) {
          getCurrentInputConnection().commitText("q̓", 1);
        // etc
```

I'd still be interested to know if there's a more elegant solution.  But this finally got me a working input method for my language.

Also, I have filed a bug with google about the keyboard's XML parser:

https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=62294