# How can I list several Unicode codes for an Android soft keyboard?

Tags: android, unicode, android-softkeyboard

So far my keys look like this:

```
<Key android:codes="97,228,230,229,64" android:keyLabel="a" android:popupKeyboard="@xml/keyboard_popup_template" android:popupCharacters="aäæå@"/>
```

I have also found out that this syntax works:

```
<Key android:codes="0x0061" android:keyLabel="a" android:popupKeyboard="@xml/keyboard_popup_template" android:popupCharacters="aäæå@"/>
```

But I want to write my codes in Unicode Hex values (because I have them already documented, our project never uses Dec values so far) and I want to explicitely list all the codes, not rely on what the popup shows as visuals.

So how can I list more than one `0xnnnn` please?

I tried `"0x0061,0x00e6,0x00e5,0x0040"` - it does not work.

I tried `"0x0061,00e6,00e5,0040"` - it does not work.

I searched on Stackoverflow and in the Android Studio help and could not find how.

I tried some flavours of `"\\u0061,\\00e6"` (as given by Android Studio help) but that does not even work for one value, let alone several.

Please help and let me know. Sorry if this is trivial to you.